# Mantener index de pagina en gridview luego de un PostBack

Tags: gridview

estoy ocupando un formato de gridview el cual se aplica con la siguiente función , esta incluye un bloque de búsqueda , un filtrado por cantidad de registros pero el problemas es que cuando la cantidad de registros excede el limite y este para a tener mas de una pagina , al seleccionar un radiobutton que esta en un templatefield en la primera columna este tiene la propiedad de AutoPostback por lo cual al recargar la tabla vuelve a la primera pagina del gridview , me gustaría saber como rescatar el index de la page actual del gridview , ya probé con la función pageindexchanging, 
Al indagar con "inspeccionar de chrome" me di cuenta de que la unica propiedad que cambia es data-dt-idx , por si favor si alguien a ocupado este formato y me pueda ayudar con este problema, programo en Visual Studio 2010 en C# asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#MainContent_gvListado").gridviewFix().DataTable({
                    language: { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json" },
                    scrollX: true
                });
            });
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!